# How to use System.Runtime.Caching in an Azure Function App

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-function-app, csx

I want to use **simple in-memory caching** of some values between function calls **in a serverless function in an Azure Function App**. I am developing directly in the Azure portal using C# script files. Following the [suggestion 2) from this blog post by Mark Heath](https://markheath.net/post/sharing-state-between-azure-functions) I have the following lines in my function's csx file:

```
#r "System.Runtime.Caching"
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System;
static MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
//.....
```

This should be the [System.Runtime.Caching assembly from this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.1).

But on complilation (save in Azure Portal), I get:

```
2021-01-05T07:25:39.687 [Information] Script for function 'Intake' changed. Reloading.
2021-01-05T07:25:39.807 [Error] run.csx(1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Runtime.Caching' could not be found
2021-01-05T07:25:39.865 [Error] run.csx(2,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2021-01-05T07:25:39.938 [Error] run.csx(4,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MemoryCache' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-01-05T07:25:40.008 [Error] run.csx(4,34): error CS0103: The name 'MemoryCache' does not exist in the current context
2021-01-05T07:25:40.041 [Information] Compilation failed.
```

This is my host.json, for reference:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**Do I need to add something here? I would have expected, adding a `#r` reference to the assembly would be sufficient.**

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspecting the documentation, apart from the well-known assemblies mentioned in the document which can be referenced with `#r`, other nuget packages, may have to be uploaded by using a `.proj` file I suspect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages

I crafted a `function.proj` file with its contents as follows

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then I uploaded `function.proj` using [App Service Editor in the portal](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/App-Service-Editor)

Once that was complete, I was able to compile `csx` successfully

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have already read this, but when reading the MS docs I have linked, I get the impression, that this assembly is included in .NET, not an extra nuget package. After all, they do not give a nuget package name there. But, if as you mentioned, which nuget package would this be?

Comment: That would be `<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="5.0.0" />`